# Mysql read lock SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, node.js

**EDIT**

I use [node.js felixge-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) and have a **pool** of mysql connections.

**ORIGINAL**

I have a mysql db in which there are 2 tables:

1. "conversations", stores metadata: user ids (2), subject, timestamp, etc.
2. "messages", stores messages that have an FK with a conversation.id

Now I always do:

1. `SELECT` a "conversation"
2. check if metadata allows requested action
3. perform an `UPDATE` on the "conversation" (change some metadata, e.g. lastUpdatedTimestamp)
4. possibly `INSERT` a message into "messages".

Next to messages a user could also `block` the conversation (from his side!)

The conversation `UPDATE` and possible message `INSERT` will happen inside a transaction.

One caveat: After I `SELECT` the conversation row and check the metadata at the application level it could be that the requested action is not allowed, leading to the `UPDATE` and possible `INSERT` never to be executed!

**Q1**

Now how to read lock the conversation row from the moment I select it? But still be able to release the lock when the metadata leads to a "user error" (e.g. current userId is not a userId in "this" conversation).

**Q2**

Right now I'm using a redis 'locks' db which locks a given id by using Lua and use node.js events to release this lock. These redis locks have a timeout. (e.g. 1000 millisecs). Is there a way to set a timeout on a mysql lock?

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` doesn't prevent read access (simple SELECT), but prevents other `SELECT FOR UPDATE` from reading locked row. If a row is locked by another session, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is hold and will be waiting until the lock will be released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. But as best I understand what you are asking, there isn't any native MySQL "lock" mechanism that is going to do what you need. (You want a session to be able to "lock" a row to prevent it from being "read" (or modified) by another session.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, that sounds like an application issue, not a database integrity issue.

The approach I would use to solve that would be to add two columns to the table:

```
locked_by   - uniquely identify the session holding the row lock
locked_at   - the date/time the row lock was placed
```

For a session attempting to obtain the lock on row, I'd check whether or not the row was already locked by a different session, and if not, mark the row as locked by this session:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET locked_by = 'me'
     , locked_at = NOW()
 WHERE unique_row_identifer = someval
   AND locked_by IS NULL;
```

If the return from the update is "zero rows updated", you know you didn't obtain a lock.
If the return is non-zero, you know you obtained a lock (on at least one row).

To check whether my session was already holding a lock on the row:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.unique_row_identifier = someval
   AND locked_by = 'me';
```

Once I knew I had an "lock" on the row, then I could retrieve it with a simple SELECT

```
SELECT ... WHERE unique_row_identifier = someval`
```

To release the lock, the session would set the `locked_by` and `locked_at` columns back to NULL.

A "read only" session could avoid reading a locked row by checking the values in the locked_by column:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.unique_row_identifier = someval
   AND t.locked_by IS NULL
```

The row would only be returned if it wasn't locked.

Note that I'd do the locking and checking in a single statement, to avoid a race condition with simultaneous situations. If I ran a SELECT to do a check, followed by an UPDATE, there's a potential for another session to slip in between those two separate statements... it would be hard to really cause that to happen, without adding a significant delay. But if we're going to bother with locking rows, we'd best do it right.

Note that the value stored in the `locked_at` column comes into play when we want to check for locks that have been held for a long time. Maybe a session took some locks, and that session has gone away, and those locks will never be released. A separate maintenance task could be scheduled to look through the table for really old `locked_at` values.

Alternatively, you could use the `locked_at` to do a more sophisticated look for a lock, and consider really old locks to be expired.

```
 WHERE ( locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < (NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR) )
```

===

NOTE:

I've never used that approach in a production system before. The problem my team is typically concerned with is the "last one in wins" scenario, where an update will potentially overwrite a change that another session has recently made. But the problem we are solving seems to be quite different from what you are trying to accomplish.

To resolve the "last one in wins" problem, we add a single "version" column (simple integer) to the table. When we retrieve a row, we retrieve the current value of the version column. When the session later wants to update the row, it verifies that no other update has been made to the row, by comparing the previously retrieved version value with the current value in the table. If the version numbers match, we allow the row to be updated, and increment the version number by one. (We do this all within a single UPDATE statement, so the operation is atomic, to avoid a race condition where two simultaneous sessions don't both do updates. We use this pattern because we don't really want to have a row locked by a session, and having the lock held forever. We're just preventing simultaneous updates from overwriting one another, which again, is different from it sounds like you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for this long answer which does what I want. Therefore I will accept this as the answer. Nonetheless I don't know yet if I will take this route, since I'm doing the same right now with a blazing fast redis db (only Lua). I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this in mysql. But since redis > mysql in terms of speed it is a hard decision to make, or not!

Comment: @aremie: I apologize for the length of my answer: the shorter answer (if I understand what you are trying to do) is that there isn't any mechanism within the MySQL database I'm aware of... apart from taking exclusive locks on the entire table, and don't want to go there because it would obliterate concurrency.

Comment: A long answer is good, since it's "to the point". It's not longer than needed! No need to apologize!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for named locks (careful, dangerous stuff, do not got around experimenting with locks on production servers :D).

Take a look at:

- [`GET_LOCK(str, timeout)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)
- [`RELEASE_LOCK(str)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock)
- [`IS_FREE_LOCK(str)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-free-lock)
- [`IS_USED_LOCK(str)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-free-lock)

**A1**: Choose a unique string to lock on and use `GET_LOCK` on it (say, `GET_LOCK('conversation_' || [id])`; if it returns `1` the lock is yours. Do whatever you want and later call `RELEASE_LOCK` (accounting for all possible scenarios, including errors).

**A2**: The second parameter of `GET_LOCK` is a timeout in **seconds**. If the operation times out `GET_LOCK` will return `0`.

### From the official documentation

> **`GET_LOCK(str,timeout)`**
>
> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string *`str`*, using a
>   timeout of *`timeout`* seconds. Returns `1` if the lock was obtained
>   successfully, `0` if the attempt timed out (for example, because another
>   client has previously locked the name), or `NULL` if an error occurred
>   (such as running out of memory or the thread was killed with
>   mysqladmin kill). If you have a lock obtained with `GET_LOCK()`, it is
>   released when you execute `RELEASE_LOCK()`, **execute a new `GET_LOCK()`<sup>1</sup>**, or
>   your **connection terminates (either normally or abnormally)<sup>2</sup>**. Locks
>   obtained with `GET_LOCK()` do not interact with transactions. That is,
>   committing a transaction does not release any such locks obtained
>   during the transaction.
>
> This function can be used to implement application locks or to
>   simulate record locks. **Names are locked on a server-wide basis<sup>3</sup>**. If a
>   name has been locked by one client, `GET_LOCK()` blocks any request by
>   another client for a lock with the same name. This enables clients
>   that agree on a given lock name to use the name to perform cooperative
>   advisory locking. But be aware that it also enables a client that is
>   not among the set of cooperating clients to lock a name, either
>   inadvertently or deliberately, and thus prevent any of the cooperating
>   clients from locking that name. One way to reduce the likelihood of
>   this is to use lock names that are database-specific or
>   application-specific. For example, use lock names of the form
>   *`db_name.str`* or *`app_name.str`*.

Bolds are mine:

1. Means that you can only hold one lock per connection (not a problem for your user case)
2. Means that locks will be released once you **close** the connection
3. Means that two different connections (even from the same pool) may not acquire the same look at once.

Comment: It won't work. I  have a node.js app which has a pool of connections. And according to this article http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/41405/14863/mysql-get_lock%28%29-explained.html `GET_LOCK()` is per connection. So when using a pool of connections, this won't work. I will edit my question to make it clear I use a pool of mysql connections. thanks for the answer though. Getting closer!

Comment: It works and you have misread the text. `GET_LOCK` can currently only hold 1 lock per connection (there is a [bug for it](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1118) open since 2003), but locks are server-wide (else they would be useless). I will update the answer quoting the documentation. Connection Pools are fine as long as you remember to release the locks.

Comment: Ok, my bad. But connections are reused, so one connection could be serving multiple users at the same time. And since there is a brief moment at the application level, the same connection could be made to `GET_LOCK()` for multiple users. Meaning multiple locks in one connection at the same time. Getting smarter by the comment!

Comment: Just read the bug report, what a bummer it's still not implemented. It would be so damn useful! http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67806

Comment: About your second comment, I'm not sure if I understand what you are implying, but if I understand you correctly you are thinking that the same active connection can be interleaved between two threads `A` and `B`. `B` should never be able to acquire the same connection as `A` before `A` releases the connection (else transactions from `A` and `B` would de mixed). A connection will only be put back on the pool after you're done with it (and when you are done with it you will have properly released the locks).

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean Anthony. But this is just becoming way too complicated. I'm sticking with my redis Lua locks db, KISS.