# Lock on row to avoid read by other user - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I'm trying to assgin a task to user by descending order of creation date in mysql "Task" table.

When two user request for task at same time, it distributes same task to both agents, how to prevent this in mysql table ? is there any locking mechanism in row level ?

I need lock on "Select" statement, for example , **Agent A and Agent B** request the task table at same time, Agent A should not get the Agent B task,

**Query :**

```
Select crm_task_id from crm_task where team = 2 order by created asc;
```

Here Agent A and B belongs to same Team = 2, when they access the page at same time, same task is assigned to both Agent, how to avoid this ?

**Note : I have used SELECT .. FOR UPDATE but still same problem occurs**

Please can anyone provide me an example!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql read lock SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720203/mysql-read-lock-select-for-update)

Comment: You can use flag column concept. When first request set this flag, then return other request with message _Task is already assigned_.

Comment: we have the flag concept, but when agent access the table same time, flag concept fails